# How can I control which error message will be showed when a field has multi errors in Spring 4.0 Validation

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm learning Spring MVC 4.0 and I has a problem in showing error message in a field:

When I leave a textbox blank, it has multi error like "Password must not be blank" and 
"Passwod lenght must be between 8 and 32 characters", i want to show only the first one message but it show all message. How can I control only the first message will be showed to user when it has many errors?

I have tried define  a custom validator but it only show one error message for all error when using @ReportAsSingleViolation

Here are my code:

Model:

```
public class User {

@NotEmpty
@Email
private String email;

@NotEmpty(message = "Password must not be blank")
@Size(min = 8, max = 32, message = "Passwod lenght must be between 8 and 32 characters")
//@CustomValidator(message = "Passwork must not be blank") //work well but doesn't meet my requirement
private String password;

@NotEmpty(message = "Please, enter your age")
@NumberFormat
@Min(value = 1, message = "Please, enter age > 0")
@Max(value = 100, message = "Please, enter age <= 100")
private String age;
```

Here is my source demo: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_siKWi32VR9U2FnYUc2ZFByLWc/view?usp=sharing

Thanks all!

Comment: can you post your custom validator?